# ImportError: cannot import name 'XGBClassifier' from 'xgboost' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, importerror, xgboost, xgbclassifier

xgboost imported successfully, but I'm not able to import XGBClassifier.

[image]

Comment: The commands work from the command line, but in Jupyter Notebook it gives the same error message. According to the [xgboost PyPI website](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/) pip installation may not work on some environments, and it may cause unexpected errors. When pip installs xgboost it creates a new xgboost folder in a non-standard (i.e. unknown) location in the same parent directory as the bin directory.

Comment: Can you tell if you are using any virtual environment ? if not, then I'd suggest you create a virtual environment and then install xgboost package in it before running jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether `xgboost` is properly installed or not.
To install `xgboost` in `anaconda` distribution, you can run the following command in anaconda command-line console.

`conda install -c conda-forge xgboost=0.6a2`or `'conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost'`

It will work fine after the installation.

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - xgboost=0.6a2